# Is there any equivalent of hyperopts lognormal in Optuna?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, hyperparameters, optuna

I am trying to use Optuna for hyperparameter tuning of my model.

I am stuck in a place where I want to define a search space having lognormal/normal distribution. It is possible in `hyperopt` using `hp.lognormal`. Is it possible to define such a space using a combination of the existing `suggest_` api of `Optuna`?

Comment: You could perhaps make use of inverse transforms from `suggest_float(..., 0, 1)` (i.e. U(0, 1)). I haven't tested it throughly, hence a comment, but here is a minimal example which might be a starting point https://gist.github.com/hvy/4ef02ee2945fe50718c71953e1d6381d

Comment: This really helps. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Great. I just reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps make use of inverse transforms from `suggest_float(..., 0, 1)` (i.e. U(0, 1)) since Optuna currently doesn't provide `suggest_` variants for those two distributions directly. This example might be a starting point https://gist.github.com/hvy/4ef02ee2945fe50718c71953e1d6381d
Please find the code below

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.special import erfcinv

import optuna


def objective(trial):
    # Suggest from U(0, 1) with Optuna.
    x = trial.suggest_float("x", 0, 1)

    # Inverse transform into normal.
    y0 = norm.ppf(x, loc=0, scale=1)

    # Inverse transform into lognormal.
    y1 = np.exp(-np.sqrt(2) * erfcinv(2 * x))

    return y0, y1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_objectives = 2  # Normal and lognormal.

    study = optuna.create_study(
        sampler=optuna.samplers.RandomSampler(),
        # Could be "maximize". Does not matter for this demonstration.
        directions=["minimize"] * n_objectives,
    )
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=10000)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_objectives)
    for i in range(n_objectives):
        axs[i].hist(list(t.values[i] for t in study.trials), bins=100)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: How to achieve lognormal when mu=0.01 and sigma=10. In the above code, if I am using mu and sigma as 0.01 and 10, then most of the trials are failing. Is that okay ?

Comment: The relationship between the inverse complementary error function `erfcinv` and `norminv` is `norminv(p)=(-sqrt(2))*erfcinv(2p)`.
Using scipy, you can compute norminv with the ppf method of the scipy.stats.norm object. The acronym ppf stands for percent point function, 
which is another name for the quantile function.
Hence you can also write `y1 = np.exp(y0)`